# Rollbar got javascript error that's not related to the code

Tags: reactjs, rollbar

Not sure if somebody ever experiencing this.
I use Rollbar for collecting error from front-end React project.
But i got some strange error like...

```
132 TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementsByName('emailconfirm_1')[0].value = ''')
```

the strange part is that, i don't have any of `emailconfirm` object in my code at all.

i grep this name to my whole project directory, including built assets, but can't find any...

Can somebody think of the possibility that could make this happen? it's just looks so weird to me.

Comment: Hey there - I'm a member of the Rollbar team.  If you're still running into this, can you contact us via `support@rollbar.com`?  It will take a bit of back & forth to sort out what's happening.

Comment: sorry, i recently found out that it's external javascript error. Thank you.

Comment: Cool, thanks for letting us know!